# What is the most flexible layout?

Tags: android, layout

What is the best layout to use to support the app on different devices (Size of screen)?

**EDIT**

I am not just talking about resizing the layout, obviously the OS does that automatically. I am talking about repositioning the objects in my layout.

by repositioning I mean moving the objects according to the size of the screen. For instance i created my layout for a larger screen which looks great, but when i run the app on a smaller device (smaller screen) some of my User Interface elements were out of the bound of my screen.

Comment: why -1? at least leave a comment and explain the reason

Comment: Nothing worse than a drive-by downvote. Upvoted to compensate. :)

Comment: @aryaxt what do you mean by repositioning?

Comment: Why should anyone be forced to explain a downvote on a question with a cryptic title, and a one-line question that is at best difficult to understand? There are cases where downvotes are unjustified and come from nowhere, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Fixed the title :) happy now ? By the way If my question was not clear enough I wouldn't get clear answers.

Comment: @Jean: Because it's not really that difficult of a question to understand. Maybe not that comprehensive of a question, but understandable.

Comment: Actually, the title shouldn't have the android word, it's enough with the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "best" layout. Almost all types of layouts will scale to different devices (Android is designed around this concept) other than AbsoluteLayout, which is deprecated anyway.

LinearLayout is best if you just have a row (horizontal or vertical) of content to insert. Using values such as dip values, fill_parent, or wrap_content will automatically adjust themselves to their content or screen size.

RelativeLayout, as Vladimir pointed out, is best for layouts where views are positioned relative to other objects within the layout. For instance, a TextView positioned beside a "Submit" button, is a common example.

FrameLayout is sort of a replacement for AbsoluteLayout; you can layer objects on top of each other, just specifying margin offsets from the sides of the frame.

TableLayout is, as it sounds, a layout for Table style design. You can have multiple rows and columns, and set certain columns to stretch to fit the size of the display, so that no matter the screen size, the layout fits as you designed.

EDIT: If you're having objects falling outside of the screen area, try wrapping your root layout in a `<ScrollView>`. This will allow the layout to be scrollable.

e.g.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        ..... //and so on
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

All Layouts are flexible in terms of size... the rule is: don't use `AbsoluteLayout`. That's all.

And with regards to the repositioning concerns... well, use always dips instead of pixels and you are good to go. Again, don't use `AbsoluteLayout`, the rest of the layouts should work fine on every screen size. Sometimes you can anticipate those "disappearing acts" by wrapping your layout in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: I was actually using AbsoluteLayout :( that might be why my view and its subviews wouldn't resize

Answer (score 0):

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) is what you should be looking at. It easily resizes the elements relative to their neighbors. Just make sure to include drawables for all resolutions and densities

Comment: in fact, any layout easily resizes the elements because the android system does this, relative layout just allows you to set them relatively to each other.

Comment: @Vladimir yes I'm aware of that. RelativeLayouts are more efficient than others though (like LinearLayout) which is why I mentioned them specifically

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout,RelativeLayout,FrameLayout are import Layouts....